# repeating the same fragment into the same layout when click button

Tags: android, android-fragments

How should I repeat the same fragment into the same layout when I click a button? When I try to repeat same fragment in linear layout below each other, it just adds first one and not the others.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_4);
    problemsLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.problemsLayout);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager =getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    for(int i =0 ; i<OperationProblemSelectTask.operationProblemList.size();i++){
        addProblemView(fragmentTransaction,OperationProblemSelectTask.operationProblemList.get(i).getMahine_problem(),OperationProblemSelectTask.operationProblemList.get(i).getMachine());
        Log.i("OperationProblemSelectTaskObjects",""+OperationProblemSelectTask.operationProblemList.get(i).getMahine_problem());
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    (MachineProblemFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment3);
}

public void addProblemView(FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction , String problem , String machine){

    problemViewFragment = new ProblemViewFragment(problem, machine);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.problemsLayout, problemViewFragment, "problemView");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see if the fragment is null. If it is not, then reuse it:

```
private void addXTOneQuickStartBoosterFragment(int animationType, boolean shouldShow) {
    String fragmentTag = getFragmentTag();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentTransactionWithAnimation(animationType);
    mXTOneQuickStartFragment = (SupplementXTOneQuickStartFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);

    if(mXTOneQuickStartFragment == null) {
        mXTOneQuickStartFragment = new SupplementXTOneQuickStartFragment();
        Bundle xTOneQuickStartBundle = getSupplementBundle(false);
        xTOneQuickStartBundle.putBoolean(SupplementXTOneQuickStartFragment.IS_ENGLISH, mIsEnglish);
        mXTOneQuickStartFragment.setArguments(xTOneQuickStartBundle);
    }
    finishFragmentAnimation(fragmentTransaction, mXTOneQuickStartFragment,  fragmentTag);
}
```